# SendInput Method in C# and Backspace Problem on RichText Box

Tags: c#, richtextbox

I am trying to send backspace to a RichTextBox editor using C# with the Sendinput method.

```
        private static void SendBackSpace(ushort charUnicode)
        {

  
            SEND_INPUT_FOR_32_BIT[] arrInput = new SEND_INPUT_FOR_32_BIT[1];

            KEYBOARD_INPUT_FOR_32_BIT ki = new KEYBOARD_INPUT_FOR_32_BIT();

            ki.VirtualKeyCode = charUnicode; // 0x08 for backspace
            ki.ScanCode = 0;
            ki.Time = 0;
            ki.ExtraInfo =0;

            SEND_INPUT_FOR_32_BIT input = new SEND_INPUT_FOR_32_BIT();
            input.InputType = INPUTTYPE.KEYBOARD;
            input.KeyboardInputStruct = ki;
            arrInput[0] = input;
            SendInput(1, arrInput, Marshal.SizeOf(typeof(SEND_INPUT_FOR_32_BIT)));
            
        }
```

When I try to send a single backspace at a time, it works fine. But when I try to send two backspace (calling this method twice), it only sends one backspace instead of two. As a result only one existing character is deleted, where as it should delete two when I call it twice.

I am capturing the Keypress events on The RichTextBox. Surprisingly the same event and same code works perfectly fine when I am using it in normal TextBox. Any help is appreciated.

FIXED:

Looks like RichTextBox in C# handles Keypress events bit differently than regular TextBox. I modified the above code with this and it works fine now. Now I can send multiple backspaces in a Loop using the following code. Hopefully this would help someone.

```
         private static void SendBackSpace(ushort charUnicode)
        {
              SEND_INPUT_FOR_32_BIT[] arrInput = new SEND_INPUT_FOR_32_BIT[2];

            KEYBOARD_INPUT_FOR_32_BIT ki = new KEYBOARD_INPUT_FOR_32_BIT();

            ki.VirtualKeyCode = charUnicode;
            ki.ScanCode = 0;
            ki.Time = 0;
            ki.ExtraInfo = 0;

            SEND_INPUT_FOR_32_BIT input = new SEND_INPUT_FOR_32_BIT();
            input.InputType = INPUTTYPE.KEYBOARD;
            input.KeyboardInputStruct = ki;
            arrInput[0] = input;

            ki.VirtualKeyCode = charUnicode;
            ki.ScanCode = 0;
            ki.Time = 0;
            ki.ExtraInfo = 0;
            ki.Flags = KEYEVENTF.KEYUP;
            input.KeyboardInputStruct = ki;
            arrInput[1] = input;

            SendInput(2, arrInput, Marshal.SizeOf(typeof(SEND_INPUT_FOR_32_BIT)));

        }
```

Comment: Check when sending second backspace still your form has focused on RichTextbox, wonder after first backspace the focus may be lost and move to other controls?

Comment: Yes it is still on focus because while typing the keypress event is captured and then the SendInput method does the rest of the logic to replace some characters and adding new one. Like I mentioned the issue is only with backspace (no other characters) that to if I call the above method more than once (say in a loop). Also, it works fine for a normal Textbox same code and same event.